# Is Agathyar (Agastya) from Ramayana same as the one who lived in Tamil Nadu 5000 years back?

Tags: history, agastya

We all know Agathyar (Agastya) had a part to play in Ramayana. But was it the same Agathyar who lived in Tamil Nadu 5000 years back as 1st Siddhar? His famous writing is Agathyar 12000 songs & his line about God was
"சக்தியே பராபரமே ஒன்றே தெய்வம்"

Comment: Yes, both of them are the same Agastya. He appears in many Puranas, the Ramayana and is also credited for creating our beautiful language Thamizh...

Comment: @HayagreevRam I thought Skanda gave Tamil to Agastya.

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri Yes you’re right. I meant popularising... I used the wrong word... sorry

Comment: It was Lord Muruga who created Tamil language and his disciple was Agathyar.

Comment: The saptrishis are immortal, so no surprise that agastya of ramayana and the tamil one are same.

Comment: Can you please transliterate and translate the last line into English? Because many can't read and understand Tamil.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Meaning God is one with two energies - Shiva and Shakti

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It translates to the following: "Shakti and Paraaparam in union is God". note that paraaparam is an epithet of Vishnu-nArAyaNa as well.

Comment: I told in simpler terms what he said. Paraaparam here he means the spiritual light which is Shiva Jyoti. Formless light of the supreme Lord is Shiva Jyoti. That's what he conveys.

Comment: What a family.. father's damaroo gives sanskrit, son's vel gives tamil